# Influx Dasboard Data Period vs. Window Period

Tags: influxdb

I have a Graph in a Influx Dashboard and the length of the plot doesn't match with the window. Why not?

[image]

The plot goes until `2021 Oct 10`, but the Window goes until `now`

Shouldn't this match automatically?

That's my (not very good) script:

```
from(bucket: "weathreapi")
  |> range(start: 2021-06-11T00:00:00Z, stop: 2021-10-03T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "hydro")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "temperature")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["loc"] == "2135")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: max)
  |> yield(name: "waterDay")

  from(bucket: "weathreapi")
  |> range(start: 2021-06-11T00:00:00Z, stop: 2021-10-03T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "hydro")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "temperature")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["loc"] == "2135")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "waterNight")

   from(bucket: "weathreapi")
  |> range(start: 2021-06-11T00:00:00Z, stop: 2021-10-03T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "smn")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "tt")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["loc"] == "BER")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "airDay")

  from(bucket: "weathreapi")
  |> range(start: 2021-06-11T00:00:00Z, stop: 2021-10-03T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "smn")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "tt")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["loc"] == "BER")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "airNight")
```

Comment: oops, my bad. It is Influx DB Dashboard not grafana.